# Trying to build a Twitter Thread programmatically

Tags: c#, twitter

I've built a Twitter application that works in C#.  It's a WPF or Windows-like application that makes a web request to the Twitter API endpoint.  Now, I have a business case to create a Twitter thread when it's sending a series of 280-character tweets.  Because of all the business rules we have, there's no way I can use an existing Twitter app on the market.

The issue is that I'm always getting a 401 unauthorized whenever I try to send a tweet with the in_reply_to_status_id_str.  In fact it does this whenever I try to add ANY OPTIONAL PARAMETERS besides the required STATUS parameter.  I'm using OAuth 1.0A.

I'm trying to create a series of Tweets that will display Show This Thread at the bottom and can be viewed together.

The method I've provided would be called in a loop for each 280-character segment.

**NOTE: I NOW HAVE THIS WORKING.  I REALIZED YOU HAVE TO ORDER THE PARAMETERS BEFORE SIGNING THEM**

```
public async Task<string> TwitterWebRequest(string status, string resource_url, string authHeader, int counter)
    {
        string id = "";
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resource_url))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
            request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["status"] = status
                };
            }
            else
            {
                data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["in_reply_to_status_id"] = "1169662308278292480",
                    ["status"] = status                    
                };
            }
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.Value.SendAsync(request))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Dictionary<string, object> jsonObj = json.DeserializeObject(responseStream) as Dictionary<string, object>;
                if (counter == 0) { id = jsonObj["id_str"].ToString(); }
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                    return "OK";
                }
                else { return ""; }
            }
        }
```

This is what I'm doing so far for the signature:

Comment: It sounds like a problem generating the OAuth signature. I'd recommend find a library that can do this for you

Comment: Indeed. Now you're sending an extra parameter `in_reply_to_status_id_str` that isn't included in the signing process.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tacoman667/4149849 might be useful

Comment: All of you above helped me.  I didn't actually have to use the Oauth library spender provided, but it made me realize I had to order the parameters alphabetically.

Comment: @CharlesOwen you should add it as a self answer so others can benefit in the future if they encounter the same problem. Glad you figured it out. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to make it work.  I had to put the parameters in order.  This is a requirement for OAuth, otherwise you'll get a 401 Unauthorized.

```
private static string CreateBaseString(string oauth_nonce, string oauth_timestamp, string status)
    {
        string baseFormat = "in_reply_to_status_id=1169662308278292480&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}"
            + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}";
        string baseString = String.Format(baseFormat, oauth.OAuth_Consumer_Key, oauth_nonce, oauth.OAuth_Signature_Method,
            oauth_timestamp, oauth.OAuth_Token, oauth.OAuth_Version, EncodingUtils.UrlEncode(status));
        return String.Concat("POST&", EncodingUtils.UrlEncode(oauth.Resource_Url), "&", EncodingUtils.UrlEncode(baseString));

    }
```